# No response returned from PHP after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue with AJAX. I have jQuery library including AJAX, this is in my index.php file. I have a form with a few fields but I'm just testing against one so I've trimmed most of the code:

```
    <form onsubmit="submitForm('#regForm'); return false;" id='regForm'>

              <div class="top-row">
                <div class="field-wrap">
                  <label>
                    First Name<span class="req">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name='firstName'/>
                </div>

              <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get Started</button> 
    </form>
```

Now, that's all well and good. The function that I'm calling "submitForm" is as follows:

```
      function submitForm(formId){
 var formData = $(formId).serialize();

 $.ajax({
    url: 'newReg.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success:function(response){
       alert(response);
   }
 });
}
```

Which I thought also looks fine, after continuously going over it, although I suspect this is where the fault lies because the PHP script it's running (newReg.php) is actually really short because I was just trying to test it out:

```
<?php 
  $response = $_POST['firstName']; 
  echo $response;
?>
```

As I've said above I think the fault lies in the submitForm function, but I have no idea what I've done wrong. Is anybody able to point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: uh.. `<function` ?

Comment: Have you checked your network tab to ensure the `$.post(..)` is actually being sent/triggered? Also, have you included the jQuery lib into your page?

Comment: @Darren Sorry, typo. The angular bracket isn't really there

Comment: @Darren I have <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script> - the network tab doesn't seem to show any post data being sent

Comment: What happens if you move the `return false;` line out of the `onsubmit` attribute and put it at the bottom of the `submitForm()` function?

Comment: Fix the typo and add an error handler to the Ajax call

Comment: @Sarcastron thanks for the suggestion, I've just gave this a go. Unfortunately it's just more of the same. Absolutely nothing seems to happen.

Comment: open up the console and what do you see?

Comment: @epascarello I'm not getting an errors in the console whatsoever unfortunately

Comment: And did you add an error handler like I suggested? Did you look at the Ajax request in the browser's network tab. The JavaScript code is good.I altered it slightly to work with jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ouf5vez/

Comment: @epascarello I added the following in `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {               
                 console.log('jqXHR:');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('textStatus:');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log('errorThrown:');
                console.log(errorThrown);
    }` However still nothing logged in the console on the browser. The ajax request doesn't show in the network tab strangely

Comment: Is the code above exactly what you have running? Next set up your console to preserve the log on page navigation. That way if the form is submitting the error message will be there.

Comment: @epascarello Yes. I have preserved the logs on page navigation. I do get file:///C:/Users/Chris/Documents/All%20website/Website%20Live/index.php?firstName=test&lastName=test&emailAddress=test%40test&passWord=test in the network logs so it is actually submitting it in some respect, it's just the alert does not return the firstName

Comment: So you are trying to run PHP without a server?

Comment: @epascarello ... Wow. I set PHP up on my web server and then was messing around locally. I've just uploaded the files and it's working on my domain... Thank you so much for your time. I can't believe I missed that. You have great patience. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This could potentially be a client side issue:

note that

```
$.(formId).serialize();
```

has a `.` between `$` and `(formId)`

Comment: thanks, hadn't seen that. Maarten also was able to spot that and point it out! I've corrected that but doesn't seem to have fixed the issue. Appreciate the help though

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = $.(formId).serialize();
```

This has an extra . between $ and (

Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: thanks, hadn't seen that. I've corrected that promptly hoping that'd be the fix but still no success! There is no errors showing in the console log which surprised me.